# Фильтрация queryset без использования менеджера

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Допустим у меня есть список объектов вот такого класса:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

ls = [<Item: Igor>, <Item: Alex>, <Item: Sandra>]
```

А также есть словарь со свойствами:

```
query = {'name': 'Igor', 'age': '25'}
```

Подскажите как отфильтровать список по этому словарю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check(item):
    for k, v in query.items():
        if getattr(item, k) != v:
            return False
    return True


filtered = [i for i in ls if check(i)]
```